# QuestionPopupFor Html Helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I need to open a jquery popup when we go onto the question mark [i have image of question mark] symbol [?]. i have 3 question mark symbols on one view called [Edit.cshtml].

1)

HQ Compatible implies that the HRA results will be used to create a Health Quotient score on the MyHealth report.

2)

If a Questionnaire is set to active "No", then the Questionnaire presentation will be terminated for all configured contracts. Setting Active to "No" will disallow the questionnaire to be added to any new contracts.

3)

If a Questionnaire is "Locked", then the Questionnaire will remain present for any active contract configured with the questionnaire. Any new contracts will not be allowed to add the questionnaire.

i wrote a j query function which calls the above three :

```
        $('#iconQuestionActiveImageDiv').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeText: 'X',
            height: 140,
            width: 200
        });
        $('.iconQuestionActiveImage').mouseover(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#iconQuestionActiveImageDiv').show();
            $('#iconQuestionActiveImageDiv').dialog({ position: [e.pageX, e.pageY] });
            $('#iconQuestionActiveImageDiv').dialog('open');
            $('.ui-dialog-title').text('Active options');
            return true;
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $('#iconQuestionActiveImageDiv').dialog('close');
            $('#iconQuestionActiveImageDiv').hide();
        });

        // 2. Locked option
        $('#iconQuestionLockedImageDiv').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeText: 'X',
            height: 140,
            width: 200
        });

        $('.iconQuestionLockedImage').mouseover(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#iconQuestionLockedImageDiv').show();
            $('#iconQuestionLockedImageDiv').dialog({ position: [e.pageX, e.pageY] });
            $('#iconQuestionLockedImageDiv').dialog('open');
            $('.ui-dialog-title').text('Active options');
            return true;
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $('#iconQuestionLockedImageDiv').dialog('close');
            $('#iconQuestionLockedImageDiv').hide();
        });

        // 3. HQ Compatible Option
        $('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeText: 'X',
            height: 140,
            width: 200
        });

        $('.iconQuestionHQCompatibleImage').mouseover(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').show();
            $('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').dialog({ position: [e.pageX, e.pageY] });
            $('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').dialog('open');
            $('.ui-dialog-title').text('Active options');
            return true;
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').dialog('close');
            $('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').hide();
        });
    });
```

Everything is working fine.

But is there any way to pass ids of div i created to reduce the length of the code.

L*** suggested me to use QuestionPopupFor Html Helper that lets you do this in the 4 places without having multiple copies of the code.

Any ideas , please reply.

---

$('.iconQuestionHQCompatibleImage').mouseover(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

```
            @Html.QuestionPopupFor("#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv");
            //$('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').show();
            //$('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').dialog({ position: [e.pageX, e.pageY] });
            //$('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').dialog('open');
            //$('.ui-dialog-title').text('Active options');

            return true;
        }).mouseout(function () {
            @Html.QuestionPopupClose("#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv");

            //$('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').dialog('close');
            //$('#iconQuestionHQCompatibleImageDiv').hide();
        });
```

I am trying to use in this way, but it isnot working.

i am writing a jquesry logic in Html Helper class as folows:

public static string QuestionPopupFor(this HtmlHelper helper, string divTag)
            {
                var javascript = string.Empty;
                //javascript = string.Concat(javascript, "$('", divTag, "').dialog({ autoOpen: false, draggable: true,resizable: false, closeText: 'X',height: 140, width: 200)");

```
            javascript = string.Concat(javascript, "$('", divTag, "').show()");
            javascript = string.Concat(javascript, "$('", divTag, "').dialog({ position: [e.pageX, e.pageY] })");
            javascript = string.Concat(javascript, "$('", divTag, "').dialog('open')");
            javascript = string.Concat(javascript, "$('.ui-dialog-title').text('Active options')");

            return javascript;
        }

        public static string QuestionPopupClose(this HtmlHelper helper, string divTag)
        {
            var javascript = string.Empty;
            javascript = string.Concat(javascript, "$('", divTag, "').dialog('close')");
            javascript = string.Concat(javascript, "$('", divTag, "').hide()");

            return javascript;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is to set each question mark to have the same class (Which presumably, they do), and add an event listener for `mouseenter` on that that class like so:

```
$(".questionMark").on("mouseenter", function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

I would also give each question mark a custom `data` attribute (such as `data-text`) containing the description (assuming that description is not too complicated). That way, you can do something like this:

```
$(".questionMark").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $("#popup").text($(this).data("text")).show();
});
```

and then to close it out:

```
$(".questionMark").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $("#popup").hide();
});
```

Do note that if you want to use a library like that, you can get and pass the ID's, and anything else in the `mouseenter` listener instead of using my suggestion.

If you want to pass the ID or any other attribute to a function do the following in the mouseenter event listener:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
myFunctionCall(id);
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks  for your reply. But my lead asked me to write a common HTML Helper Class, so that we can call that helper class for ant view through the application and we can pass ID's of the Div tag that have text message.

Comment: its giving the error for the method you mentioned:  Object doesn't support property or method 'show'

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i pass ids to the library class?

Comment: Hi @MyInfo sorry it didn't work for you. Not sure what you mean by "HTML helper class". I'll update my answer to include a demo ID pass.